# Getting different results from the same form in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to create an ajax form using laravel. The display is a table with names and next to the names are buttons enclosed by forms to do actions.

Here is the html:

```
<div style="margin-top: 100px;">
<h2>Character settings</h2>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Map</th>
        <th>Move</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($chars as $char)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$char['name']}}</td>
        <td>{{$char['map']}}</td>
        <td>
            {{Form::open(array('action' => 'UsersController@move', 'id' => 'mover'))}}
            <input type="hidden" name="charID" id="charID" value="{{$char['id']}}" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-info">Move</button>
            {{Form::close()}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Here is the javascript ajax processing:

```
$('#mover').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $( this ),
    method = $form.attr( "method" );
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{action('UsersController@move')}}",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $('#charID').val(),
        type: method,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(reponse['test']);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the controller:

```
public function move() {
    return Response::json(array('test' => 'test'));
    exit();
}
```

The table looks like:
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHYh7.png)

If I click the first button for Sambte, it works and I see "test" in the console. But when I click the 2nd link it doesn't send as ajax and sends me to a new page with the json object as the content of that page so I see {"test":"test"} in the new page it brought me to.

I can't figure out what's wrong. Hopefully its a small error somewhere.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ID's` are unique, you need to use a `class` on the form instead.

```
'class' => 'mover'
```

Then just use the `class` instead of the `ID` in the selector

```
$('.mover')
```

Sidenote, the same needs to be done for the `charID`, here's how I'd tackle that:

```
class="charID"
```

then, in your submit handler:

```
data: $form.find('.charID').val()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I completely forgot that I'd need to deal with that property of IDs in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('submit','.mover', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $( this ),
    method = $form.attr( "method" );
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{action('UsersController@move')}}",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: method,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(reponse['test']);
        }
    });
});
```

change id=mover to class=mover

Comment: Thank you as well!